# Detect rectanglular signature fields in document scans using OpenCV

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to extract rectangular big boxes from document images with signatures in it. Since i don't have training data (for deep learning), i want to cut rectangular boxes (3 in all images) from these images using OpenCV.

Here is what I tried:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('S-0330-444-20012800.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,1)
contours,h = cv2.findContours(thresh,1,2)
for cnt in contours:
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt,0.02*cv2.arcLength(cnt,True),True)
    if len(approx)==4:
        cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,(26,60,232),-1)

cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

## [sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0oyB.jpg)

With the above code, I get a lot of squares (around 152 small points like squares) and of course not the 3 boxes.

Replies appreciated. [sample image is attached]

Comment: is there any way you can obtain a clearer image? it's very hard to detect anything with good precision

Comment: no, the input data documents we have are such images only.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you read up on [template matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_matching). There is also a good [OpenCV tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html) on this.

For your use case, the idea would be to generate a stereotyped image of a rectangular box with the same shape (width/height ratio) as the boxes found on your documents. Depending on whether your input images show the document always in the same scaling or not, your would need to either resize the inputs to keep their magnification constant, or you would need to operate with a template bank (e.g. an array of box templates in various scalings).

Briefly, you would then cross-correlate the template box(es) with the input image and (in case of well-matched scaling) would find ideally relatively sharp peaks indicating the centers of your document boxes.

Comment: thanks for the idea, i have tried "template-matching" too but the images have taken roughly so the boxes are inclined/sloped, i guess that's the reason this solution is not working.

Comment: template matching is only good for very controlled environments; his images aren't very clear.

Comment: Well, if one doesnt have an intrinsically controlled environment it is advisable to take control. In OPs case that would imply a geometrical transformation mapping documents imaged from arbitrary angles and distances to a standardized orthonormal angle and scaling. For that you could use landmarks on e.g. the box edges in an input and a reference image (with a reference camera angle and scaling) to constrain an affine transformation which then corrects for these parameters

Answer (score 0):

In the code above, use image pyramids (to merge unwanted contour noises) and `cv2.findContours` in combination. Post to that filtering list of Contours based on contour area `cv2.contourArea` will lead to only bigger squares.

There is also an alternate solution. Looking at images, we can see that the signature text usually is bigger than that of printed text in that ROI. so we can filter out contours smaller than signature contours and extract only the signature.

Its always good to remove noise before using `cv2.findContours` e.g. dilate, erode, blurring etc.